# inserting xml element into multiple nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, nodes

I have the following XML

```
<ROOT>
  <FSM338_Container>
    <FSM338_Details>
      <RunDate>2013-05-29 09:43:00</RunDate>
      <Uic>21690</Uic>
      <Date>2013-06-10 00:00:00</Date>
      <CASHBREAK>199</CASHBREAK>
      <CASHLUNCH>199</CASHLUNCH>
    </FSM338_Details>
    <FSM338_Details>
      <RunDate>2013-05-29 09:43:00</RunDate>
      <Uic>21690</Uic>
      <Date>2013-06-10 00:00:00</Date>
      <CASHBREAK>199</CASHBREAK>
      <CASHLUNCH>199</CASHLUNCH>
    </FSM338_Details>
  </FSM338_Container>
  <BillingReport>
    <RunDate>2013-05-29 09:43:00</RunDate>
    <Uic>21690</Uic>
    <Date>2013-06-10 00:00:00</Date>
    <gaindacd>1</gaindacd>
    <docnum>07000F</docnum>
  </BillingReport>
  <DataElements>
     <unitid>12345</unitid>
     <fbocost>0.00</fbo>
  </DataElements>
</ROOT>
```

I need to load the xml doc and add in several elements whenever I find the element named "Uic" .  In short if I find "Uic" add in the element `<someElement>my stuff here</someElement>` at the same level as UIC at all locations.

I'Ve used

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(@"path_to_xml.xml");
list = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Uic");
```

I used insertBefore to add in my element but I can get it to copy to only the first element

Comment: Are you able to use LINQ to XML instead of XmlDocument? It would make it a lot easier.

Comment: Your Xml is malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SelectNodes() method of XmlNode which accepts xpath expression.

```
XmlNodeList nodes = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Uic");
foreach(XmlNode node in nodes) {
   XmlElement element = xDoc.CreateElement("SomeElement");
   element.InnerText = "anything";
   node.ParentNode.AppendChild(element);
}
```